# Using sprockets outside of Rails -- directives not working

Tags: ruby, coffeescript, sprockets

I'm trying to use Sprockets with CoffeeScript files outside of Rails, but the directives aren't processed:

```
# app.js.coffee
#= require models/user
# some other code...
```

Now, that file is processed with:

```
require 'sprockets'
root = 'some path...'
env = Sprockets::Environment.new(root)

env.append_path(File.join(root))
env.append_path(File.join(root, 'models'))

compiler = Sprockets::StaticCompiler.new(env.index,
                                         'output',
                                         %w(app.js.coffee),
                                         :digest => nil,
                                         :manifest => false)
compiler.compile
```

The code from `app.js.coffee` does get compiled, but the contents from `models/user` aren't included (and no error is raised).

This is with Sprockets 2.0.3.

Any ideas?

Comment: By the way, I pulled that code out of `actionpack/lib/sprockets/assets.rake`.

Comment: since you're already successfully using sprockets outside of rails, would you mind helping me figure it out too? http://stackoverflow.com/q/11267677/48523

Answer (score 0):

Oh dear, after diving into the source for an hour or so, I found out that Sprockets will only listen to directives at the top of the file, a fact also stated in the docs, which I somehow missed...

Comment: Yeah, I am looking for a way to have requires not at the top of the file.  Any luck?