# Using Sprockets as a standalone service for a PHP application

Tags: php, ruby, zend-framework, sprockets

I would like to duplicate the Rails asset pipeline feature in my Zend Framework PHP project. I think that it's possible to use the Sprockets gem as a standalone service but I am not sure how to configure it properly. I'm not interested in porting Sprockets to PHP, nor using a PHP port of Sprockets. The Sprockets rubygem already has everything I need. I just need to figure out how to set it up in a non-ruby environment.

**Update:** I have figured out how to run Sprockets as a Rack application. Now I'm interested in the differences between development and production environments. How does the Rails view helper generate all the `<link>` and `<script>` tags in development and fingerprint a single file in production?

Answer (score 6):

You're probably just going to have to dig into the source for [Sprockets](https://github.com/sstephenson/sprockets) and [Sprockets integration with Rails](https://github.com/rails/rails/tree/3-2-stable/actionpack/lib/sprockets) in order to really come up with a good solution for your problem, but I hope some of these pointers will help.

First, check out `Sprockets::Helpers::RailsHelper#javascript_include_tag`:

```ruby
1  def javascript_include_tag(*sources)
2    options = sources.extract_options!
3    debug = options.key?(:debug) ? options.delete(:debug) : debug_assets?
4    body  = options.key?(:body)  ? options.delete(:body)  : false
5    digest  = options.key?(:digest)  ? options.delete(:digest)  : digest_assets?
6
7    sources.collect do |source|
8      if debug && asset = asset_paths.asset_for(source, 'js')
9        asset.to_a.map { |dep|
10         super(dep.pathname.to_s, { :src => path_to_asset(dep, :ext => 'js', :body => true, :digest => digest) }.merge!(options))
11       }
12     else
13       super(source.to_s, { :src => path_to_asset(source, :ext => 'js', :body => body, :digest => digest) }.merge!(options))
14     end
15   end.join("\n").html_safe
16 end
```

At a high level, this method does the following:

1. Determine whether to concatenate everything into a single file or include all assets individually (line 3).
2. Determine whether we should include the digest string in the asset filename (line 5).
3. For each given source file, retrieve the `Sprockets::Asset` object corresponding to that source file (line 8).
4. If we're debugging, call the superclass method with each `Asset` required by this one. `Sprockets::Asset#to_a` returns such an array (lines 9–10).
5. If we're not debugging (or if we fail to retrieve an `Asset` object for some reason), call the superclass method with the top-level `Asset` (or the source filename as a string) (line 13).

Many of those methods are pretty simple and only depend on the environment you set up. For example, `digest_assets?`:

```
def digest_assets?
  Rails.application.config.assets.digest
end
```

Some of this configuration is saved in `Rails.application.assets`, which itself is a `Sprockets::Environment` object. You can actually play with this on the Rails console to get familiar with it (I'd highly recommend [the awesome_print gem](https://github.com/michaeldv/awesome_print) if you aren't already familiar with it):

```
1.9.3p194 :001 > Rails.application.assets.class
Sprockets::Environment < Sprockets::Base
1.9.3p194 :002 > Rails.application.assets['application.js'].class
Sprockets::BundledAsset < Sprockets::Asset
1.9.3p194 :003 > Rails.application.assets['application.js'].to_a.map(&:digest)
[
    [ 0] "6bb424b2409c6a5fb28acd15cc184b16",
    [ 1] "0ff3e5680ead3dadeee021c144835311",
    [ 2] "4c908739f93e83bda6b5e84f7ab10a29",
    [ 3] "319003f54b9408b4e41b0199e1848423",
    [ 4] "3f52cd966b6bb99a8f7994f5dcd7767f",
    [ 5] "c50a6aac16f6a69deeb722fe51e36c54",
    # ...
]
```

So essentially, Sprockets is responsible for determining dependencies, concatenation, and digesting of your assets, and Rails just ties it together with its helpers. It looks like you should be able to replicate this behavior in your framework in a reasonably straightforward manner.

Comment: Did you ever write anything that might help spit out the debug <script> / <link> tags?